# Use Url.Action to generate fully qualified anchor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url.action, postal

I'm using Url.Action to generate link in e-mails (with the Postal MVC Framework) that was sent by my application, however, the links generates are showing with "localhost" name, and not domain name.

I'm using the following code:

```
@Url.Action("AlterarSenha", "Account", null, this.Request.Url.Scheme)
```

The result is the following:

```
http://localhost/Account/AlterarSenha
```

After that, I tried the following code:

```
@Url.Action("AlterarSenha", "Account", null, this.Request.Url.Scheme, Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"])
```

And I got the same result.

How can I get the link with my domain like:

```
http://www.servicili.com/Account/AlterarSenha
```

Comment: `@Url.Action("AlterarSenha", "Account")`

Comment: Result: `http://account/AlterarSenha`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to use your domain name in the URL even when the application runs on localhost, you could use this overload of `Url.Action`:

```
public virtual string Action(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    string protocol,
    string hostName
)
```

And pass your domain name as `hostName`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: As you can see, it is the code that I was using, however, I'd like to know if is possible the APP determine the hostname, instead I put it in the Url.Action

Comment: Not unless you have access to the  HttpContext.Current.Request object in your email-sending class, which has the UserHostName property and other info.

Answer (score 1):

if your local server uses port 80 you can use

```
Url.Action("AlterarSenha", "Account",null, null, "www.servicili.com");
```

Result is

```
http://www.servicili.com/Account/AlterarSenha
```

If your project uses any other port (like 123) the result will be

```
 http://www.servicili.com:123/Account/AlterarSenha
```

Also you may set protocol as  https it won't add any port

```cs
Url.Action("AlterarSenha", "Account",null, "https", "www.servicili.com");
```

The result is

```
https://www.servicili.com/Account/AlterarSenha
```